# PHP loop though MySQL and update existing values

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a script that pulls data from an XML feed consisting of models online and inputs the results into a MySql database, that part I have working just fine...

I have a "status" field that shows if the model is online or offline, the XML feed only contains models that are actually online so I have the query set to REPLACE INTO and that builds up a database of them all eventually...

Problem is the status field always contains the value "online" so I am trying to run a query that will loop though all the rows and change the status value to "offline" before the main query is run to parse the current XML feed data...

Using :

```
$query = "SELECT status FROM models";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\nQuery: $query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
mysql_query ("UPDATE models SET '$row[1]'=offline WHERE '$row[1]'");
}
```

No error is generated but nothing gets updated either... $row[1] being the "status" field...

I have also tried using a mysql_num_rows query with a for loop without much success either other than I was able to echo the contents of "status" in every row but unable to achieve the desired results, either it replaced them all with "offline" regardless or replaced nothing at all...

Appreciate any help given please guys.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and links on that... though I'm still having trouble fully grasping the "old" technique lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT status FROM models";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\nQuery: $query");
 mysql_query ("UPDATE models SET status='offline' WHERE status='online'");
```

PS: Thats the way all your code should looks like.....aps, and dont use the mysql extension; go for mysqli or PDO instead and the red box and blabla XD

Saludos ;)

Comment: And, to prevent confusion, you *dont* have to run this query in a loop. This query will 'toggle' the status of all records in the database

Comment: Is that because $result contains every value for "status" in every row already ? This is where I been getting mixed up then...

Comment: @RobertRozas Thanks for that man it is working like a charm now ! I would not mind but I was trying to use that very query to begin with but placing it in a for loop and also trying with a while statement, no wonder it was not working... Thanks again much appreciated !